# Is it necessary to convert arguments to Array before calling apply?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, apply

Are there any browser restrictions or any other issues that prevents me from doing:

```
fn.apply(this, arguments);
```

versus:

```
fn.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
```

I know that `apply` takes a "true" `Array` as second argument, but passing an arguments collection seems to work just as good. or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), it "Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array (or an array like object)".  Given that `arguments` is an array-like object, there shouldn't be any restriction on using it.

In fact, the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Description) explicitly says `arguments` is a valid parameter.

Comment: I thought so too, but I keep seeing `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` in so many "professional" code examples, I figured there must be a valid reason...

Comment: It's necessary if you want to do Array operations on them, such as append, shift, or push, so most developers I know do it more out of habit than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

## The support is [unknown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#compat-desktop) on MDN.

Only Firefox is known to accept Array-like objects for the second argument of `Function.prototype.apply()`. I would exercise caution before passing `arguments` directly.